# Jupyter lab File Load Error for filename.ipynb Failed to fetch

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am running a `jupyter lab` instance on a remote server which I connect to with a public IP address. Recently the error `Jupyter lab File Load Error for filename.ipynb Failed to fetch` has started appearing out of nowhere when I open the file. The connection to `jupyter` is solid and all the other files are opening and saving as they should, moreover, I am able to execute `os.system('cat filename.ipynb')` and see the output as normal. While I was writing this, one of the notebooks has stopped working without any reason and I have no clue how to fix this because I have changed nothing there. I thought that the issue may be in the fact that the system has multiple users, but I have made sure that the `jupyter lab` instance was launched with the same user who has the affected files. I have also checked the `stat filename.ipynb` for both working and broken files and the output is completely identical. The icing on the cake is the fact that I can run `cat working_file.ipynb > tempfile.ipynb` and the resulting file will not open. What could cause this?